# count empty values in array

Tags: javascript

Given an array:

```
var arr = [1,,2,5,6,,4,5,6,,];
```

Count how many **empty** values is has: (length - length after removing the empty values)

```
var empties = arr.length - arr.filter(function(x){ return true }).length;

// return 3
```

or something like this

```
arr.empties = arr.length;
arr.forEach(function(x){ arr.empties--  });

// arr.empties returns 3
```

Is this the best way or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm trying to find the smallest snippet possible

Comment: `arr.length - arr.filter(Number).length`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Based on your comments to another answer, it looks like you're after the shortest method.  Well, you might want to consider a variation of your own example:

```
var empties = arr.length - arr.filter(String).length;
```

All you're doing is passing a native function rather than an anonymous function, saving a few precious bytes. Any native constructor or function will do, as long as it doesn't return a boolean.

---

You need to be more specific about what you would consider the 'best way'.  For instance, some methods will give better performance than others, some are more concise and some have better compatibility.

The solutions you mention in the post require browsers to be compatible with the ECMAScript 5th Edition specification, so they won't work in some older browsers (read: IE8 and lower).

The "best" all-round approach is a simple loop.  It's not as concise as your methods, but it will no doubt be the fastest and most compatible:

```
var arr = [1,,2,5,6,,4,5,6,,], count = 0, i = arr.length;

while (i--) {
    if (typeof arr[i] === "undefined")
        count++;
}
```

This makes use of loop optimisations (using `while` and decrementing is faster than `for`).

Another approach would be to sort the array so that `undefined` items are all at the end and use a loop to iterate backwards:

```
var arr = [1,,2,5,6,,4,5,6,,], count = 0;
arr.sort();
while (typeof arr.pop() === "undefined") count++;

alert(count); 
//-> 3
```

This approach would modify the original array and remove those items which may not be what you want.  However, it *may* be much faster on very large arrays.

> **Performance test suite**
>   http://jsperf.com/count-undefined-array-elements

Comment: your first approach doesn't work.. why `arr.length - 1` and not just `arr.length` ?

Comment: @vsync: it started as a for loop. When I changed it, I forgot to remove the -1. Fixed :-) I also added a shorter version of your own method after seeing your comment on @stecb's answer.

Comment: @vsync: you might want to try asking on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com if you want to get it even smaller.  Let me know if you do and I'll post my answer there.

Answer (score 5):

Looks good to me.

You could also do:

```
var empties = arr.reduce(function(x, y){ return x-1; }, arr.length);
```

Also, if you don't mind sorting the array, you might get a little added performance out of:

```
arr.sort();
for (var j=arr.length-1; j > 0 && arr[j] === undefined; j--) {}
var empties = arr.length-j-1;
```

Comment: Thanks--I love `reduce`--Under-appreciated I think

Comment: you can even do the recudtion without the 'y' argument, cause it's not used anyway

Comment: Yeah--I just put it for redundancy in showing what reduce has available.

Answer (score 1):

Or, without using js 1.6 filter/foreach, you could cycle it yourself this way:

```
var arr = [1,,2,5,6,,4,5,6,,];
var emptyElems = 0;
for(var i=0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++){
    emptyLength += (arr[i] === undefined) ? 1 : 0;
}

alert(emptyElems); //alerts 3
```

Comment: yes clearly, but i'm trying to find the smallest snippet possible, no matter the compatibility

Comment: Oh I didn't know about 'smallest' : )

Comment: emptyElems != emptyLength